# Load schema into h2 from sql-file in java

Tags: java, testing, h2

I have a sql-file containing several statements like this:

```
create table user (
name varchar(255) not null,
active INTEGER default 1 not null,
valid_from DATETIME not null,
valid_to DATETIME not null,

primary key (name));
```

I would like to re-use this already existing file for test-purposes.

How can I load this from Java into H2 to create a new schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 options:

- The [RUNSCRIPT](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#runscript) SQL statement
- You can also use the RUNSCRIPT SQL statement [in the database URL, as an INIT script](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection).
- The [RunScript](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/RunScript.html) tool (command line, or call one of the methods).